# Using socialoauth to get twitter/facebook data

Tags: facebook, twitter, oauth

I'm using socialoauth (http://code.google.com/p/socialoauth/) to implement twitter & facebook logins for a web site. The site is php and mysql based.

I've got logins implemented and working, but I need to get the users screen name or email so that I can store their preferences about my site in a mysql database. I'm not sure how to go about getting their information once I've got the oauth_token and oauth_secret. I couldn't find any documentation or examples using socialoauth, aside from getting the logins working.

I downloaded twitteroauth (https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth), and mismashed that together with socialoauth.php via this tutorial (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/) and was able to get the twitter user's information, but I would prefer to use only socialoauth.php because it does logins for both facebook and twitter.

Specific question: does anyone know which functions in socialoauth are used to get the user's information (hopefully for both twitter and facebook)? I'm very new to this, so it's possible I saw the function I needed while I was looking through the code, and simply didn't recognize it as what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter does not provide access to users email addresses. The users Twitter screen_name should be returned in the same request you get their access token however.

With Facebook you have to ask for the [email permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#user_friends_perms) and then their email address should be accessible with the profile details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for specific help with the library/script I am using though, not at what sort of info I am able to get via different permissions.